# Error when compiling a sample Boost ASIO program using boost 1.82 and MINGW

Tags: boost, mingw-w64, asio

So i am trying to compile the absolute basic ASIO tutorial code as given [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1.html)

I am using MINGW 64 for compiling.
However i am getting a bunch of linker errors in the terminal :

```
Starting build...
D:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -I D:\boost\boost_1_82_0
"D:\Development\simplefolder\simpleclient.cpp" -o "D:\Development\surviving mars\simplefolder\simpleclient.exe"
D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc44Ri3w.o: in function `boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::startup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&, unsigned char, unsigned char)':
D:/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:39: undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc44Ri3w.o: in function `boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::cleanup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&)':
D:/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:56: undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc44Ri3w.o: in function `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::get_last_error(boost::system::error_code&, bool)':
D:/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:87: undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc44Ri3w.o: in function `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*, boost::system::error_code&)':
D:/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:2202: undefined reference to `__imp_select'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```

I tried various simple things like trying to include <boost/system.hpp> But that didn't work. This is a simple default application which should work out of the box

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution to be
In the arguments add 3 extra libraries as follows:

```
D:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -I D:\boost\boost_1_82_0 "D:\Development\simplefolder\simpleclient.cpp" **-l gdi32 -l wsock32 -l ws2_32** -o "D:\Development\simplefolder\simpleclient.exe"
```

Adding 3 Additional Libraries: `-l gdi32 -l wsock32 -l ws2_32`
solved it

Comment: Your answer could be further improved by including a short explanation why your answer solves the problem.